# Why does "ls .." show real parent content when I'm inside a symbolic link directory?

Tags: linux

```
$ cd ~
$ ln -s /real/folder symbolic_link

$ cd symbolic_link
$ cd ..
$ ls -l
symbolic_link -> /real/folder/

$ cd symbolic_link
$ ls -l ..
folder
```

In other words, why the behaviour of `cd ..` is different from `ls ..` when you are inside a symbolic linked directory?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your shell tracks the symbolic links that led you to your current working directory. `cd` is a shell builtin and `help cd` states (example from `bash`):

> Options:
>   `-L` force symbolic links to be followed: resolve symbolic links in DIR after processing instances of `..`
>   `-P` use the physical directory structure without following symbolic links: resolve symbolic links in DIR before processing instances of `..`
>   […]
>   The default is to follow symbolic links, as if `-L` were specified.

You can try `cd -P ..` and see the difference. Another example is `pwd -L` and `pwd -P` (while `pwd` is also a shell builtin).

Note the default behavior can be changed by `set -P` and `set +P`. See `help set` for more details.

On the other hand `ls` is a separate executable that doesn't benefit from this tracking ability of your shell. However you can make it follow symbolic links with this trick:

```
(cd -L .. && ls -l)
```

Basically we use `cd` to change the current working directory with respect to symbolic links (and I explicitly used the default `-L` option for that), then invoke `ls -l`. The `&&` operator means `ls` will be executed only if `cd` succeeds. Parentheses `()` make all that is inside be executed in a subshell. This is the trick: `cd` command affects this subshell only and in your main shell nothing changes, there's no need to `cd` back.

Comment: Thanks for helping me understand the difference between shell builtins and linux tools!