# Check if two paths are the same, even if their strings don't match exactly

Tags: linux, bash, directory-listing

I have a script that depends on some environment variables, some of which are paths

The script checks if it's being run in the correct directory by checking `$(pwd)/expected-subdir` against `$VARIABLE_PATH/expected_subdir`

Of course if `$VARIABLE_PATH == $(pwd)/` (I naturally appended a slash to the end of the variable when typing it), the string match fails even though the directories are technically sane.

Is there a way to uniquely identify a directory, given a path to it, and see if another path will route you to the same spot? It's possible the path given is not sane, so this check should still be done, but it seems unnecessary to force the path to exactly match, when a stray slash or even a relative directory (I know these can be bad sometimes) would route you to the same spot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This other answer](https://superuser.com/a/1396650/432690) mentions `stat`. Let's improve the approach:

```
a="$(stat --format=%d:%i -- "$(pwd)/expected-subdir/")"         || printf "Error A\n" >&2
b="$(stat --format=%d:%i -- "$VARIABLE_PATH/expected-subdir/")" || printf "Error B\n" >&2
[ "$a" = "$b" ] || printf "Not the same path.\n" >&2
```

Notes:

- We're using `stat --format=`, so no further parsing is required.
- `%d` is device number, `%i` is inode number. The latter alone is not enough because two objects on different devices (filesystems) may have the same inode number.
- The shell is smart enough to separately handle quotes inside and outside `$( )`.
- `printf`-s are just stubs for error handling. In the real script you'd probably want something like

  ```
  [ "$a" = "$b" ] || { printf "Not the same path.\n" >&2; exit 2; }
  ```
- Nonexistent path will make `stat` throw an error.
- Trailing slashes are important. If `foo` is a symlink to a directory, `stat foo` will examine the symlink while `stat foo/` will examine the directory. Alternatively research `stat -L` and use it maybe.
- `--` is in case `$(pwd)` or `$VARIABLE_PATH` begins with `-` (see guideline 10 [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html#tag_12_02)).

---

There are `readlink -f` (also mentioned in the other answer) and `realpath` utilities. One of them may be a better approach than `stat`. It depends on which aspects of paths are important to you. Main differences:

1. If `/foo/bar/` is a bind mount to `/moo/baz/` then `stat --format=%d:%i` will tell you they are the same, but `readlink` or `realpath` will consider them different.
2. The situation gets complicated with symlinks and `..`. See [`man 1 realpath`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/realpath.1.html), especially `-L` and `-P` options.

With symlinks involved, if your script changes the directory upwards (towards `/`, e.g. `cd ..`), you may get different results depending on where you start, even if `stat` or `readlink -f` says the two starting points are the same (compare [*Why does `ls ..` show real parent content when I'm inside a symbolic link directory?*](https://superuser.com/a/1217241/432690)). Consider this approach:

```
# early in the script
set -P
cd .   # seems like no-op but updates the PWD variable to physical path
```

With bind mounts involved, if your script changes the directory, you may get different results depending on where you start, even if `stat` says the two starting points are the same. Consider the example with `/foo/bar/` and `/moo/baz/` (already introduced above). It's obvious `/foo/` may be completely different than `/moo/`. But also `/foo/bar/abc` may be different than `/moo/baz/abc` because any `abc` may be an independent bind mount to something else. So not only `cd ..` may place you in a different spot, but also `cd abc`.

Well, `abc` may be a file. What if you bind another file to `/moo/baz/abc` but not to `/foo/bar/abc`? The perceived files will be different even if `stat` says you're in the same place!

Because of these problems you may indeed prefer `readlink` or `realpath` over `stat`.

---

`stat`, `readlink` and `realpath` are not required by POSIX. In your case a portable solution may look like this:

```
a="$(cd -P -- "expected-subdir" && pwd -P)"                || exit 1
b="$(cd -P -- "$VARIABLE_PATH/expected-subdir" && pwd -P)" || exit 1
[ "$a" = "$b" ] || { printf "Not the same path.\n" >&2; exit 2; }
```

It works by `cd`-ing to either path and retrieving it with `pwd`. These operations are explicitly forced to act "physically" (`-P`).

`set -P` is not POSIX either. If you want POSIX shell to "emulate" `set -P`, replace `cd` and `pwd`:

```
cd()  { command cd  -P "$@"; }
pwd() { command pwd -P "$@"; }
```

POSIX requires the last `-P` or `-L` option to take effect, so `pwd -L` still retrieves the logical path even though the function "injects" `-P`; the same for `cd -L`.

Answer (score 1):

You can compare their inode numbers, which can be obtained from `ls -i`

```
ls -di path/to/dir
```

(`-d` prevents `ls` from showing the inode ids for the contents of the directory);

or from `stat`

```
stat path/to/dir | grep -o 'Inode:\ [0-9]*' | cut -d' ' -f2
```

You can also use `readlink -f` to get the full path to the directory.

Comment: For scripting, it might be easier to use `find path/to/dir/ -maxdepth 0 -printf %i\\n` as that prints just the inode, and not the name. The `maxdepth 0` prevents a deep search. For extra safety, add `%D` since inodes are only unique per disk, not systemwide.