# Symbolic link points to seemingly invalid location, yet it works

Tags: linux, symbolic-link

Let's assume that the root folder of what I'm working with is `frameworks/av`, and this folder have the following content:

```
-rw-rw-r--  1 <user> <user>    94 Mar 21 14:34 Android.bp
drwxrwxr-x  8 <user> <user>  4096 Mar 21 14:34 camera/
-rw-rw-r--  1 <user> <user>  5394 Jul 16  2018 CleanSpec.mk
drwxrwxr-x  4 <user> <user>  4096 Jul 16  2018 cmds/
drwxrwxr-x  8 <user> <user>  4096 Jul 16  2018 drm/
drwxrwxr-x  2 <user> <user>  4096 Mar 26 21:30 .git/
drwxrwxr-x  8 <user> <user>  4096 Mar 21 14:34 include/
drwxrwxr-x 25 <user> <user>  4096 Mar 21 14:34 media/
-rw-rw-r--  1 <user> <user>     0 Mar  2  2018 MODULE_LICENSE_APACHE2
-rw-rw-r--  1 <user> <user> 17680 Mar  2  2018 NOTICE
-rw-rw-r--  1 <user> <user>    76 Jul 16  2018 OWNERS
drwxrwxr-x  3 <user> <user>  4096 Mar 21 14:34 packages/
drwxrwxr-x 14 <user> <user>  4096 Mar 21 14:34 services/
drwxrwxr-x  2 <user> <user>  4096 Jul 16  2018 soundtrigger/
drwxrwxr-x  3 <user> <user>  4096 Mar 21 14:34 tools/
```

In `frameworks/av/include/media/stagefright`, I find this link, `foundation`, which by its description should point to `frameworks/av/foundation/...`:

`lrwxrwxrwx 1 <user> <user> 57 Jul 16  2018 foundation -> ../../../foundation/include/media/stagefright/foundation//`

What really puzzles me is that there is no folder `foundation` in `frameworks/av`, yet I can follow the link just fine. The real target, as given by `readlink -f foundation`, is `frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/foundation/include/media/stagefright/foundation`.

What is going on here? How can `foundation` magically translate into `media/libstagefright/foundation`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you descend into `frameworks/av/include/media/stagefright` there is at least one symlink you go through. In effect the logical path is `frameworks/av/include/media/stagefright` but the physical one is not.

Then the symlink in question goes three levels up (`../../../`) and further from there, but this uses the physical directory structure you're obviously not aware of. Your shell may still track the logical path though.

Compare [*Why does `ls ..` show real parent content when I'm inside a symbolic link directory?*](https://superuser.com/q/1217237/432690)