# Different behavior of double dots and symlinks in Windows and Unix

Tags: windows, unix, filesystems, ntfs, symbolic-link

Under unix, `symlink/..` refers to the parent directory of the target. While experimenting with symlinks and junctions in Windows, I could see that `symlink/..` refers to the parent directory of the symlink itself, not of its target.

So:

```
A
|--Link_To_C           [ symlink to B/C ]
|--B
   |--C
```

In Unix: `A/Link_To_C/..` resolves to `A/B`.
In Windows: `A/Link_To_C/..` resolves to `A`

First question: is it always like that?

If so, could I normalize any (local) path in Windows using, for example, [os.path.normpath](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.normpath) in Python, without having problems for symlinks? The documentation says:

> Normalize a pathname by collapsing redundant separators and up-level
>   references so that A//B, A/B/, A/./B and A/foo/../B all become A/B.
>   This string manipulation may change the meaning of a path that
>   contains symbolic links

(worth reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34865153/os-path-normpath-and-symbolic-links)

Is it correct to say that this does not apply to Windows?

Comment: For Linux, compare [this](https://superuser.com/q/1217237/432690).

Comment: Thanks, your response in the link was really helpful! Anyway, here I am more interested in what the OS APIs do, for example [open](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) on Unix and [CreateFile](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilew) on Windows.