# bash move file relative to its position

Tags: linux, bash, file-management, mv

As the title says, can I move a file relative to its current position?

Let's assume I am in the root directory, with the following file structure:

```
...
├──home
   └──user
      ├──Documents
      └──Downloads
         └──foo.bar
...
```

I want to move `foo.bar` from Downloads to Documents.
You could do `mv /home/user/Downloads/foo.bar /home/user/Documents/`,
but when the directory structure is a bit deeper it is annoying to have to write the nearly same path again.

Is there some way to say, for example:

`mv /home/user/Downloads/foo.bar (whatever operator)/../Documents/`.

so that the file gets moved relative to its position, one directory up, and into Documents?

Comment: "but when the structure is a bit deeper it is annoying to write the nearly same path again" - Copy/paste is your friend.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### With [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html#Brace-Expansion)

```
echo mv /home/user/Downloads/{foo.bar,../Documents/}
```

(remove `echo`  if the result looks good).

Note this generates `/home/user/Downloads/../Documents/` as the target path. I deliberately used the string you chose when introducing your "whatever operator": `../Documents/`. But if `Downloads` is a symlink then `/home/user/Downloads/../` may resolve to something other than `/home/user/`; in such case `/home/user/Downloads/../Documents/` won't be equivalent to `/home/user/Documents/`

<sup>(Trivia: `cd /home/user/Downloads/../Documents/` may be equivalent to `cd /home/user/Documents/`. This does not mean `mv` will see the paths as equivalent. Compare [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1217241/432690).)</sup>

Usually (or if the symlink could interfere) you would simply use `/home/user/Documents/` as the target (and you in fact did). This path does not depend on `Downloads` being a symlink or not. For this reason you may prefer the following brace expansion:

```
echo mv /home/user/{Downloads/foo.bar,Documents/}
```

Its form does not emphasize the "relative" aspect (while `../` in our first command does, I guess), still it saves you typing `/home/user/` again.

Brace expansion is not specified by POSIX. It works in Bash and in few other shells, but not in pure `sh`.

---

#### After `cd`

You can simply `mv foo.bar ../Documents/` if you `cd /home/user/Downloads/` first. Do it in a subshell and the current working directory of the main shell will not be affected:

```
(cd /home/user/Downloads/ && mv foo.bar ../Documents/)
```

Notes:

- Thanks to `&&` if `cd` fails for whatever reason (e.g. a typo in the path) then `mv` won't run.
- Again, if `Downloads` is a symlink then `../Documents/` may be different than `/home/user/Documents/`.

Answer (score 2):

You can reference your home directory with `$HOME` or with `~`.

**Example:**

`~/Downloads` is the same as `/home/user/Downloads`.

You can also use `.` to reference the current working directory and `..` to reference the parent directory.

**Example:**

```
$ pwd     
/home/mashuptwice/test
$ cd ..        
$ pwd
/home/mashuptwice
```

If you need to reference a directory more often in a shell session, you can also save it into a variable.

**Example:**

```
$ dl="$HOME/Downloads"                                                                                                                                                                                     
$ echo "$dl"
/home/mashuptwice/Downloads
$ cd "$dl"
$ pwd
/home/mashuptwice/Downloads
```

Answer (score 1):

Another method would be using `dirname` to get the directory part of the path

```
file=/here/is/a/file
echo mv "$file" "$(dirname "$file")/newfile"
```

result:

```
mv /here/is/a/file /here/is/a/newfile
```

Comment: i think that should be ```mv "$file" "$(dirname "$file")/newfile"```  otherwise it won't work if the file is a descendant of a folder with spaces in its name; eg this works with `/foo_bar/file` but it doesn't work with `/foo bar/file`  (also fwiw it's not uncommon that bash scripts fail on files/folders with spaces in its name)

Comment: Yes. It would have worked for the question, but in general quotes are always an good idea. For something I type interactively I usually have an idea if I need them or not, but if you're unsure use them.